# Fix for missing 'tr' class in webscraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape different stocks by rows, with the data scraped from https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500. I am following a tutorial using a similar website, however that website uses classes for each of its rows, while mine doesn't (attached below).

[image: 1]

[image: 1]

This is the code I'm trying to use, however I don't get any output whatsoever. I'm still pretty new at coding so any feedback is welcome.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

company = []
symbol = []

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500' #Data from SlickCharts
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')

for i in rows:
    row = i.find_all('td')
    print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add some headers to your request because most likely you get the same as me: status code `403 Forbidden`. It's because the website is blocking your request. Adding `User-Agent` does the trick:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Then you can iterate over `tr` tags as you do. But you should be careful, because, for example first `tr` doesn't have `td` tags and you will get exception in the row:

```
print(row[0])
```

Here is the example of code that prints names of all companies:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

company = []
symbol = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500' #Data from SlickCharts
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    all_td_tags = row.find_all('td')
    if len(all_td_tags) > 0:
        print(all_td_tags[1].text)
```

But this code also outputs some other data besides company names. It's because you are iterating over all `tr` tags on the page. But you need to iterate over a specific table only (first table on the page in this case).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

company = []
symbol = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500' #Data from SlickCharts
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

first_table_on_the_page = soup.find('table')
rows = first_table_on_the_page.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    all_td_tags = row.find_all('td')
    if len(all_td_tags) > 0:
        print(all_td_tags[1].text)
```

Comment: Ok yeah now I see the other tables included... For that, will I need to make a new variable "table" and specify the table I want to use?

Comment: If I correctly understand what you mean, yes. Updated my answer for clarification.

Comment: In the end I have made my own solution to deal with this problem, but once again thanks for your feedback! I personally included `table1 = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-hover table-borderless table-sm'})` and used it in the for loop. Thanks!